# Does closing, say, vim, trigger sys_exit?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am curious as to when the sys_exit system call is actually called in Linux. I am writing a module to track system calls and find that when I open and close vim I do not necessarily immediately register a call to sys_exit. Sometimes the call appears to be delayed instead.

Does anyone know the top-secret semantics behind this? Are we SURE it calls sys_exit immediately upon ":wq!" or ":q!" or is there some more dastardly workings afoot?

Comment: When you say "delayed", what order of magnitude are you talking about? Microseconds, milliseconds, seconds, minutes? This would also apply to what you mean by "immediately".

Comment: Keeping in mind I am printk'ing in my module upon a system call triggering, thus have to "dmesg" to find the results - the order of magnitude is in seconds. Like several seconds. I will dmesg over and over and after 7-8 seconds the exit will appear.

Comment: I wonder if you are actually hitting a buffer to stdout that is causing the delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sys_exit should be called each time you stop a process normally:

exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 14439 detached

What do you see in strace?